# Programmatically accessing arbitrarily deeply-nested values in a dictionary

Tags: python, search, dictionary

I'm working on a Python script where I'm given lists of strings of the format: `['key1', 'key2', 'key2.key21.key211', 'key2.key22', 'key3']`.

Each value in the list corresponds to an entry in a dictionary, and for entries structured like `'key2.key21.key211'`, they correspond to (in this example), a key `'key211'` nested within `'key21'`, itself nested inside `'key2'`.

The above list corresponds to the dictionary:

```
x = {
     'key1' : 'value1',
     'key2' : {
               'key21' : {
                          'key211': 'value211'
                         },
               'key22' : 'value22'
              },
     'key3' : 'value3'
    }
```

The names are not necessarily as regular as `key(n)+`; they can be of the form `food.vegetables.potato`, for example. The only guarantees I have is that the *key names themselves*, in the dictionary, do not contain the `.` character, and that the dictionary definitely contains all the entries referenced in the original list.

My question is, given such a list of strings, how do I programmatically access the corresponding entries in a dictionary? I can think of a solution using `eval()`, as well as one using just a traversal/search, but I want to avoid calls to `eval()`, and I get the impression that a traversal with comparisons would be slow (since `dict`s aren't search trees), and would entail a lot of nasty exception handling.

Comment: You should try something yourself and then edit the question to include the code you came up with.

Comment: Let me see if I am reading your question correctly: what you need to do is split each key (string) on `'.'`, then access `original_dict[k[0]][k[1]][k[2]]...` for however many resulting k's there are?

Comment: @Two-Bit exactly that. quamrana I'll update with a tentative solution in about a half hour.

Comment: What do you mean *"search"*? You have the key for each level, so retrieving the value is an `O(1)` operation.

Comment: @jonrsharpe but python doesn't have facilities for accessing arbitrarily deep keys programmatically, afaik

Comment: There's no `dict` method for it, but it's trivial to write an iterative/recursive function to apply it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One approach is to write a function to access keys in nested dicts.

```
def deep_access(x,keylist):
     val = x
     for key in keylist:
         val = val[key]
     return val

s = 'key2.key21.key211'

print deep_access(x,s.split('.'))
```

result:

```
value211
```

---

Another approach, if you want to use similar syntax as a normal dictionary access you could subclass `dict` and override `__getitem__` to allow for nested access when a tuple of keys is provided:

```
class NestedDict(dict):

    def __getitem__(self,keytuple):
        # if key is not a tuple then access as normal
        if not isinstance(keytuple, tuple):
            return super(NestedDict,self).__getitem__(keytuple)
        d = self
        for key in keytuple:
            d = d[key]
        return d

>>> nd = NestedDict(x)
>>> nd['key2']
{'key22': 'value22', 'key21': {'key211': 'value211'}}
>>> nd['key2','key22']
'value22'
>>> nd['key2','key21']
{'key211': 'value211'}
>>> nd['key2','key21','key211']
'value211'
```

You can then similarly implement `__setitem__` and `__delitem__` as needed.

Comment: This second solution is so useful I wonder how it is not available in a library of some sort?