# Convert list to a sequence of dictionary keys

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 dictionaries

```
old_dict = {'key1': {'password1': 'password', 'sensitive_data': {'MY_PASSWORD': 'old_passwrd'}},
            'key2': 'next_password', 'useless_key': 'useless_pass'}

new_dict = {'key1': {'password1': 'password', 'sensitive_data': {'MY_PASSWORD': 'default_password'}},
            'key2': 'next_password'}
```

Next code parses the keys in the new dictionary and takes values ​​from the old one and inserts them into the new one

```
def find_old(val_dict, value_list):
    for i in value_list:
        val_dict = val_dict[i]
    return val_dict


def change_value(val_dict, value_list, value):
    if len(value_list) == 1:
        val_dict[value_list[0]] = value
    elif len(value_list) == 2:
        val_dict[value_list[0]][value_list[1]] = value
    elif len(value_list) == 3:
        val_dict[value_list[0]][value_list[1]][value_list[2]] = value


def parser(parse_dict, value_list=None, level=0):
    if value_list is None:
        value_list = []
    for i in parse_dict:
        value_list = value_list[:level]
        value_list.append(i)
        next_val = parse_dict[i]
        if type(next_val) is dict:
            parser(next_val, value_list, level=level + 1)
        else:
            old_value = (find_old(old_dict, value_list))
            change_value(new_dict, value_list, old_value)


parser(parse_dict=new_dict)
print(new_dict) # {'key1': {'password1': 'password', 'sensitive_data': {'MY_PASSWORD': 'old_passwrd'}}, 'key2': 'next_password'}
```

the code works, but the change_value function can only work with 3 levels of dictionary keys. how to convert this function into a loop?

Comment: What is the `find_old` function supposed to do? Seems like it overwrites the dictionary with the value of the first item of the list as key

Comment: @Ftagliacarne no it returns value from list of keys and old_dict

Comment: You should probably look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30648317/programmatically-accessing-arbitrarily-deeply-nested-values-in-a-dictionary) and create your own `NestedDict` class. Accessing the value is indeed feasible with a for loop (see the same question), but I cannot think of a way to set it (which is what you need).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is already an operator that implements this future (Python 3.9). Its name is **merge** and the operator is `|`, syntax: `dict_1 | dict_2` ([official doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.values)).
Python will overwrite the left dictionary with the value of the keys from the right dictionary if there is an overlap, otherwise it will merge.

In your example, with these dictionaries:

```
old_dict = {
    'key1': {
        'password1': 'password',
        'sensitive_data': {
            'MY_PASSWORD': 'old_passwrd'
        }
    },
    'key2': 'next_password',
    'useless_key': 'useless_pass'
}

new_dict = {
    'key1': {
        'password1': 'password',
        'sensitive_data': {
            'MY_PASSWORD': 'default_password'
        }
    },
    'key2': 'next_password'
}
```

The code is:

```
new_dict = new_dict | old_dict
```

If you want to remove `useless_key` as well, you can use a recursion function:

```
def _rmv_item(obj: dict, key_to_rmv: str):
    # remove useless key
    if key_to_rmv in obj: obj.pop(key_to_rmv)
    # search other dictionaries
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            _rmv_item(v, key_to_rmv)

def _rmv_items(obj: dict, keys_to_rmv: list[str]):
    # remove useless key
    for key in keys_to_rmv:
        if key in obj:
            obj.pop(key)
    # search other dictionaries
    for k, v in obj.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            _rmv_items(v, keys_to_rmv)
```

Comment: didn't know about merge, thank you! but what if old dictionary have many useless_keys?

Comment: @AlexDie I updated my answer, I write two function that you can use to remove any key(s) do you want

Answer (score 0):

I figered out and it works

```
def change_value(val_dict, value_list, value):
    key_seq = val_dict
    for index, i in enumerate(value_list):
        if index != len(value_list)-1:
            key_seq = key_seq[i]
        else:
            key_seq[i] = value
```